# Lenovo ideapad 5-15ARE05 firmware upgrade, how to?

Tags: lenovo, hardware, bios, 20.10, firmware

Running a Lenovo ideapad 5-15ARE05 (4800u) (shipped with FreeDos) without major issues with Ubuntu 20.10.

Touchpad, graphics and display are working fine with the 5.8 kernel.

Although the fingerprint reader is not working (yet), a major annoyance is the fan kicking in too soon.

There seems to be a [new firmware E7CN36WW](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/5-series/ideapad-5-15are05/81yq/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI) (WIN10 only), addressing that issue.

Downloaded that file, and inspection ([innoextract | wine /EXT](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/flash-your-lenovo-ideapad-laptop-bios-from-linux-using-uefi-capsule-updates-a82e455ea29c)) gives several files:

```
WinFlash64.exe
WinFlash32.exe
ShellFlash64.efi
ShellFlash32.efi
SctWinFlash32.exe
LinFlash64
LinFlash32
DosFlash.exe
default.rsp
default_SMT.rsp
default_REL.rsp
Crisis64.efi
Crisis32.efi
BIOS.cap
AndroidFlash64
AndroidFlash32
E7CN36WW.exe
```

Any idea how to proceed? The .cap option? The files do suggest DosFlash should be possible, and what is LinFlash32/LinFlash64?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_15are05#Flashing_the_BIOS_from_Linux) creating a FreeDos bootable USB-drive should do the trick.

Copy over E7CN36WW.exe, the file you get after innoextract the download (and before extracting with wine).

Boot the flashdrive, and run the BIOS executable.

Please READ the [linked page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_15are05#Flashing_the_BIOS_from_Linux) carefully before trying this out.